# In Java generics, what does List<? super String> mean?

Tags: java, generics

Can anyone explain how this both can compile and how it works?

```
List<? super String> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

As I understood it, the implementation of this needs to be either a String list or a list of objects that have String as super class? Have I missed something?

Comment: BTW - The String class is final and no class extends it.

Comment: Yeah I know, only a case that came up for java cert test exam =)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No (i.e. yes, you have missed something :-) . `<? super String>` is any class which is a *superclass* of `String` (including `String` itself). (In this case, the only other suitable class is `Object`.)

What you described would be `<? extends String>` (which in this specific case wouldn't be very useful as `String` is `final`, so it can have no subclasses).

Answer (score 5):

`<? super String>` accepts `String` and any *superclass*.

Not to be confused with:

`<? extends String>` accepts `String` and any *subclass* (of which there aren't any since `String` is `final`).

Answer (score 0):

Since `String` is `final`, it can't be the super class of any other class. `List<? super String>` means any type that is a super class of `String`. In fact, `Object` is a super class of `String` (of any class actually).